# Jest encountered an unexpected token when testing react-native with jest

Tags: reactjs, react-native, testing, jestjs

I want to use jest on my react-native project. I'm new to jest and react-native.
currently getting below error

```
Details:

/Users/sachigrannan/SKO/Alpha4-1/node_modules/react-native-iphone-x-helper/index.js:1
import { Dimensions, Platform, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

  at Runtime._execModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1157:58)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-navigation-stack/lib/commonjs/vendor/TransitionConfigs/CardStyleInterpolators.tsx:2:1)
```

I have set this in package.json. Please help!

```
"jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "preset": "react-native",
    "cacheDirectory": "./cache",
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "./app/utils/vendor"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "statements": 80
      }
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(react-native|my-project|react-native-button|nodejs-mobile-react-native|react-navigation)/)"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Did you found solution for this ?

Comment: I have the same issue but I use react-native-web and react-navigation

Comment: Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Given that your transformIgnorePatterns worked before introducing the lib, the trick is simply to add "react-native-iphone-x-helper" to the "transformIgnorePatterns" attribute.

```
"node_modules/(?!(react-native|my-project|react-native-button|nodejs-mobile-react-native|react-navigation|react-native-iphone-x-helper)/)"
```

That said, you may be better off just deleting "transformIgnorePatterns" and letting the `"preset": "react-native"` config do its job.

The only problem I've had with the preset has been when I've had an untranspiled dependency in a nested node_module directory, eg.

```
/path/to/myproject/node_modules/@react-navigation/bottom-tabs/node_modules/react-native-iphone-x-helper/index.js:1
    import { Dimensions, Platform, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
           ^
```

In this case the problem was that another module used a different version of `react-native-iphone-x-helper` so I had to update that dependency so they aligned. If that's not feasible you have yarn's [resolutions field](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/)